# Custom HTTP headers always get added under "Access-Control-Request-Headers"

Tags: angularjs, http, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS. I am writing a simple client to pull data from a HTTP endpoint.

All headers I set are sent over the wire under the header `Access-Control-Request-Headers`, but not as actual HTTP headers in the request.

```
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
var config = {
  headers:  {
    'customHeader1': 'value1'
  }
};
$http.defaults.headers.get = {
  'customHeader2': 'value2'
};
$http.get("http://localhost:8280/abc",config).success(function(data) {
  // alert(data);
  $scope.names = data.records;
}).error(function(response, data, status, header) {
  alert(status);
});
```

Comment: This is per CORS specification for preflighted request. Angular doesn't have any role into it.Once server allows the CORS communication by sending appropriate header the original get request will be called with actual HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try that suggestion from the official [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

To explicitly remove a header automatically added via `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` on a per request basis, Use the headers property, setting the desired header to undefined. For example:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```